# How to translate word problem to mathematical statement

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have this math problem.

...$x$ animals are positioned at random points of a circle with 1 kilometer
circumference. Every animal has a certain amount of calories stored in fat. Once an animal $m$
reaches another $n$, it can eat $n$ and gain 100% of $n$’s fat. There is enough fat distributed between all $x$ animal to fuel any single one of them for 1 kilometer. Prove that there is an animal
that can run around the circle clockwise, eating everyone as he goes, and run out of fat
just as he reaches his starting point.

I can intuitively decipher that it requires some form of induction to prove. That is for if we assume n animals can do it, then n+1 animals can do it too. But I'm unable to come up with a mathematical statement $P(n)$ to induct on, that describes the question.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: First show that there must be at least one animal, $A_1$, among the $n+1$ who has enough calories to reach the next animal, $A_2$. Remove $A_2$, and give $A_1$ all of $A_2$’s calories in addition to its own. Apply the induction hypothesis to the remaining $n$ animals to conclude that one of them can complete the circle, and show that the same animal can complete the circle of $n+1$ animals.